# Powerful sort of techno pad

Tags: sound-design, synthesis, replication

Im trying to create this pad, its really nice and powerful.  I tried creating it via Massive using a smooth and hard square wave,  It seems like the attack is a bit fast but exponential.  I also realise there is alot of reverb to it.  I also kind of sounds like the reverb is revered and then washed out again.  I also made it so that filter is 12db and at 2 2:30 with a slight enveloper on the filter with medium attack and decay.

I cant seem to get the right sound.  Seems like there might be something Im just missing, or it could be that Im not using the right synth.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz7u6sri5SdsR1hoeG0zMDZ5Vms/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not sound like it comes from an analog synth but more along the lines of a string ensemble sound. It'd be impossible to recreate this sound in a virtual analog-modeled synth, not even a digital one either.

Comment: thanks so much for that,  I though I was getting something close with the oscillators but sounds so cool it wasnt coming out the way I wanted.  so an ensemble.  Do you recommend any sort of effects to get close to that

Comment: Orchestral string ensembles are all acoustic, not analog nor digital.
They're played by the means of bowing the strings of an instrument in the Violin family.
A good, free place to look for some of these string ensembles would be various orchestral sound fonts. Off-hand, the SGM soundfont has an excellent set of sounds, including some really nice strings.